# How to implement single sign on using Active Directory credentials on OSX

Tags: macos, active-directory, single-sign-on, ntlm

I am trying to get a Mac application using a WebView browser to login to the web server automatically (single sign on) using the credentials of the logged in user.

The Mac is joined to a Microsoft Domain Server, and the user logs into the Mac as a Domain user.

I've searched and searched but haven't been able to find anything describing or even mentioning whether this is possible.  Is it?  If so, how?

Our application currently has a login page where the user can type in a username and password, which is easy enough to authenticate with using NSURLConnection Delegate, etc.  But the NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM connection challenge requires a known username and password, which I obviously can't get from the logged in user.

Yes, we can save the typed in credentials into the keychain to automatically user for subsequent logins, but the idea is to allow the user to automatically login the very first time and not require the user to retype in the same credentials they just logged in to the Mac with.

Oh, we only need to support 10.8 and above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through some simple experimentation.  Safari will automatically attempt to respond to the NTLM challenge using the logged-in user's credentials.  I didn't have to do anything programmatically to support it.

Comment: How did you make it working? I'm working on same kind of requirement, so need more information from you.